# thread doesn't run inside android service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I want to use a service for background downloads I can't get thread to start inside my service. run method is never called (I have tried both local and separate process services)

```
    public class DownloadService extends Service
    {
        private int count = 0;

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate()
        {
            super.onCreate();
            //mDT.start(getApplicationContext(), new Handler());
            new Thread(new DownloadRunnable());
        }


        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }



        private class DownloadRunnable implements Runnable
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                ++count;
                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hey from Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }

//inside application class
Intent i= new Intent(this, DownloadService.class);
startService(i);
```

The toast never appears and breakpoints inside run are never fired.
Do I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you dont start the thread

```
new Thread(new DownloadRunnable()).start()
```

Comment: you create the thread but nothing else: new Thread(new DownloadRunnable());

Comment: I was afraid it's something embarassing. I have now idea what happened to the .start(), cause it was there in the previous version of code. IDE should generate warning for this, when a thread is created without start or assignment to a variable.